# Change accessibility focus in react-native app on drawer/modal open

Tags: reactjs, accessibility, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm trying to improve accessibility on a react native app and am facing the following problem: when the user opens the menu drawer, the focus doesn't change to the modal drawer content. Instead swiping left and right focuses content that's in the background.

I have tried setting dynamic accessibility props to the drawer and main content area:

```
<NavigationMenu
    importantForAccessibility={isNavigationVisible ? 'yes' : 'no-hide-descendants'}
/>
<DashboardContent
    importantForAccessibility={isNavigationVisible ? 'no-hide-descendants' : 'yes'}
/>
```

Where `isNavigationVisible` is a prop that gets updated when the drawer opens, but this had no effect.

Is there any way to force the focus change to the drawer when it opens?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what i ended up using:

```
const setFocus = ({ current: ref }) => {
    const FOCUS_ON_VIEW = 8;
    const reactTag = findNodeHandle(ref);

    Platform.OS === 'android'
        ? UIManager.sendAccessibilityEvent(reactTag, FOCUS_ON_VIEW)
        : AccessibilityInfo.setAccessibilityFocus(reactTag);
}
```

Comment: Can you please give a brief note how to use it in a component..

Answer (score 4):

Currently, React-Native doesn't provide a way, to out-of-the-box, traverse the view tree and get the first focusable element to set the focus for it.

So you need to use `AccessibilityInfo.setAccessibilityFocus` passing a `reactTag` case by case.

Comment: But this method works only on Android. What to use for IOS?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a bug on `AccessibilityInfo.setAccessibilityFocus(reactTag)`, it doesn't work consistently and calling it more than once increase the chance of success.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64173514/2069407) for how to make this call twice to do the focus on view launch.

See this open [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/30097) on github for more detail.