# setAccessibilityFocus using ref not working

Tags: react-native, accessibility, voiceover, talkback

I'm using the `ref` prop along with `findNodeHandle` on a bunch of components in order to be able to trigger `AccessibilityInfo.setAccessibilityFocus`. However, it's not always working as expected. Sometimes the reference is `null` even though `componentDidMount` has executed.

I'm often using `setAccessibilityFocus` in order to focus the header of a new element which appears on the screen, for example when opening a modal.

IMPORTANT: This is Voiceover/Talkback functionality so you'll need to have that activated on your device.

See my snack: https://snack.expo.io/@insats/example-accessibilityinfo-setaccessibilityfocus-not-working

This is the code sample:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  findNodeHandle,
  TouchableOpacity,
  AccessibilityInfo,
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';

class Sample extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.accessibilityRef = null;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('componentDidMount');
    this.setAccessibilityFocus();
  }

  setAccessibilityRef(el) {
    console.log('setAccessibilityRef', el);
    this.accessibilityRef = el;
  }

  setAccessibilityFocus() {
    console.log('setAccessibilityFocus', this.accessibilityRef);

    if (this.accessibilityRef) {
      const reactTag = findNodeHandle(this.accessibilityRef);
      AccessibilityInfo.setAccessibilityFocus(reactTag);
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log('Rendering Sample');

    return (
      <Text ref={this.setAccessibilityRef}>
        This text ought to be read out loud by the screenreader if enabled
      </Text>
    );
  }
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    open: false,
  };

  toggle = () => this.setState({ open: !this.state.open });

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ margin: 50 }}>
        <StatusBar hidden />
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{ backgroundColor: 'blue', padding: 20, marginBottom: 20 }}
          onPress={this.toggle}>
          <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>
            {this.state.open ? 'Hide text' : 'Show text'}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        {this.state.open && <Sample />}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `AccessibilityInfo.setAccessibilityFocus(reactTag);` might fix this issue, found it in the last code example here -> https://medium.com/@jessicalynnebyrne/setting-focus-for-accessibility-in-react-native-cd7bbe891c5d. It looks like your way works for web apps but not for native apps, sadly I do not know react so I could be wrong!

Comment: @GrahamRitchie `AccessibilityInfo.setAccessibilityFocus(reactTag);` is precisely what I'm using but there seems to be some kind of race condition. If I wrap the setAccessibilityFocus call in a setTimeout with ~20ms delay, it works more often. But that solution causes new problems (such as the call being triggered even though the component has dismounted). It's also not very reliable since the timeout is just a guesstimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer that worked for me in an old comment on [this React Native Github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/22807#issuecomment-496263621).

Essentially, you need to apply the `accessible` tag to the component that is receiving the `ref`.

```
<TouchableOpacity
    accessible
    ref={setInitFocusRef}
    onPress={() => {}}>
  <Text>Blah blah</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

You may also need to wrap your component in a `<View>` and put these there instead of the component itself as some components, like `<Text>` from React Native Paper, don't work unless wrapped.

```
<View accessible ref={setInitFocusRef}>
  <ComponentToBeFocused />
</View>
```

Additionally, my code checks to make sure that the `reactTag` always exists before calling `setAccessibilityFocus()` to avoid the situation where it's `null` intermittently.

For example:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const reactTag = findNodeHandle(setInitFocusRef.current);
    if (reactTag) {
      AccessibilityInfo.setAccessibilityFocus(reactTag);
    }
  }, [setInitFocusRef]);
```

(Forgive my lack of React Class knowledge, but I believe the equivalent of `useEffect` in this situation would be `componentDidMount` and/or `componentDidUpdate`)

Comment: Adding `accessible` to the `Text` component in my example fixes the issue  With that said, your answer should make it clear that the idea of "wrapping" is only for when the component doesn't support the `accessible` prop.

Answer (score 4):

I don't really understand what is causing these issues. I've found that calling the setAccessibilityFocus twice solves the problem. You can simplify the logic of focusing by just handling everything in the callback ref as well.

Example:

```
export default () => {

    const setInitFocus = (element: React.Component | null) => {
        if (element == null) return;
        const elementId = findNodeHandle(element);
        if (elementId) {
            AccessibilityInfo.setAccessibilityFocus(elementId);
            AccessibilityInfo.setAccessibilityFocus(elementId);
        }
    };

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {}}
          ref={setInitFocus}
        >
            <Text>Blah blah</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
};
```

Here's your snack with those changes applied:

https://snack.expo.io/@loganlim/example-accessibilityinfo-setaccessibilityfocus-not-working

Comment: I've added the issue to the react-native github as well. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/30097